# Injecting collection of beans vs using ApplicationContextAware to getBeansOfType

Tags: spring

If I do

```
@Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
    myBeans = applicationContext.getBeansOfType(MyBean.class).values();
}
```

does that have exactly the same effect as putting this in my constructor?

```
@Inject
public MyClass(Collection<MyBean> myBeans) {
    this.myBeans = myBeans;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in commot case yes (without @Lazy ,@Value , required...), they are do the same effect.

In a Spring application, the two annotations works the same way as Spring has decided to support some JSR-299 annotations in addition to their own.

But there are some annotation that doen't hendled by @Inject like - laze , required as it's part of spring but not part of jsr.

Looks like if - all that you get by @Inject for Collection myBeans you get in spring also , but it's not true for all getted by spring also loaded by @inject

here is blog about comparison @AUTOWIRED AND @INJECT [SPRING INJECTION WITH @RESOURCE, @AUTOWIRED AND @INJECT](https://blogs.sourceallies.com/2011/08/spring-injection-with-resource-and-autowired/#more-2350)